# Incorrect conversion from object to JSON?

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, object, nsdictionary

I need to send to a web service this JSON by POST:

```
{
  "plantilla" : "IL3\/il3_prof",
  "contacto" : {
    "email" : "vgonzalez@ub.edu",
    "nombre" : "Vanesa",
    "movilPersonal" : "934037680",
    "apellidos" : "Gonzalez Jimenez."
    "direccionTrabajoDTO" : {
      "direccion" : "Feixa Llarga, S\/N 08970 Hospitalet De Llobregat (Barcelona), España"
    },
  },
  "valoresPlantilla" : [
    {
      "key" : "nombre",
      "value" : "Vanesa Gonzalez Jimenez."
    },
    {
      "key" : "curso",
      "value" : "Curs de test per Tecnologia"
    },
    {
      "key" : "linked",
      "value" : "es.linkedin.com\/in\/"
    },
    {
      "key" : "direccion",
      "value" : "Feixa Llarga, S\/N 08970 Hospitalet De Llobregat (Barcelona), España"
    },
    {
      "key" : "email",
      "value" : "vgonzalez@ub.edu"
    },
    {
      "key" : "telefono",
      "value" : "934037680"
    }
  ]
}
```

I created the object Tarjeta with values:

```
Tarjeta *tarjeta = [[Tarjeta alloc] init];
tarjeta.plantilla = @"IL3/il3_prof";

Contacto *contacto = [[Contacto alloc] init];
contacto.nombre = @"Vanesa";
contacto.apellidos = @"Gonzalez Jimenez.";
contacto.email = @"vgonzalez@ub.edu";
contacto.movilPersonal = @"934037680";

DireccionTrabajo *direccionTrabajo = [[DireccionTrabajo alloc] init];
direccionTrabajo.direccion = @"Feixa Llarga, S/N 08970 Hospitalet De Llobregat (Barcelona), España";
contacto.direccionTrabajo = direccionTrabajo;

tarjeta.contacto = contacto;

ValorPlantilla *nombre = [[ValorPlantilla alloc] init];
nombre.key = @"nombre";
nombre.value = @"Vanesa Gonzalez Jimenez.";
ValorPlantilla *curso = [[ValorPlantilla alloc] init];
curso.key = @"curso";
curso.value = @"Curs de test per Tecnologia";
ValorPlantilla *linked = [[ValorPlantilla alloc] init];
linked.key = @"linked";
linked.value = @"es.linkedin.com/in/";
ValorPlantilla *direccion = [[ValorPlantilla alloc] init];
direccion.key = @"direccion";
direccion.value = @"Feixa Llarga, S/N 08970 Hospitalet De Llobregat (Barcelona), España";
ValorPlantilla *email = [[ValorPlantilla alloc] init];
email.key = @"email";
email.value = @"vgonzalez@ub.edu";
ValorPlantilla *telefono = [[ValorPlantilla alloc] init];
telefono.key = @"telefono";
telefono.value = @"934037680";

tarjeta.valoresPlantilla = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:nombre, curso, linked, direccion, email, telefono, nil];

return tarjeta;
```

After this, I do a conversion from object to JSON with this method:

```
NSMutableDictionary *tarjetaDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[tarjetaDict setValue:tarjeta.plantilla forKey:@"plantilla"];

NSMutableDictionary *contactoDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[contactoDict setValue:tarjeta.contacto.nombre forKey:@"nombre"];
[contactoDict setValue:tarjeta.contacto.apellidos forKey:@"apellidos"];
[contactoDict setValue:tarjeta.contacto.email forKey:@"email"];

[contactoDict setValue:tarjeta.contacto.movilPersonal forKey:@"movilPersonal"];

NSMutableDictionary *direccionDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[direccionDict setValue:tarjeta.contacto.direccionTrabajo.direccion forKey:@"direccion"];

[contactoDict setValue:direccionDict forKey:@"direccionTrabajoDTO"];

[tarjetaDict setValue:contactoDict forKey:@"contacto"];

[tarjetaDict setValue:tarjeta.valoresPlantilla forKey:@"valoresPlantilla"];

return tarjetaDict;
```

When I finish this process, I send the NSMutableDictionary like JSON to the web service, but it says that's incorrect and this is the error.

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Invalid type in JSON write (ValorPlantilla)'
```

I'm doing anything wrong?

Comment: Please share your error

Comment: 'tarjeta.valoresPlantilla = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[nombre toJSON], [curso toJSON], [linked toJSON], [direccion toJSON], [email toJSON], [telefono toJSON], nil];' Here did not requires to convert in json just add object here.

Comment: Okey, I've already tried it but it says an error. @Shreyank

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this method to your ValorPlantilla class

```
-(NSMutableDictionary *)getobject
{
    NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

    [dict setObject:self.key forKey:@“key"];
    [dict setObject:self.value forKey:@“value"];

    return dict;
}
```

And Change this line

```
tarjeta.valoresPlantilla = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[nombre getobject], [curso, linked getobject], [direccion getobject], [email getobject], [telefono getobject], nil];
```

This might works

Comment: Thank you... @Lion

Answer (score 1):

First make below six individual dictionary,

```
 {
  "key" : "nombre",
  "value" : "Vanesa Gonzalez Jimenez."
},
{
  "key" : "curso",
  "value" : "Curs de test per Tecnologia"
},
{
  "key" : "linked",
  "value" : "es.linkedin.com\/in\/"
},
{
  "key" : "direccion",
  "value" : "Feixa Llarga, S\/N 08970 Hospitalet De Llobregat (Barcelona), España"
},
{
  "key" : "email",
  "value" : "vgonzalez@ub.edu"
},
{
  "key" : "telefono",
  "value" : "934037680"
}
```

Then create one array let's say `temp` array, add this all six dictionary to that array.

Then make below dictionary let's say  `tempDic`,

```
   "contacto" : {
"email" : "vgonzalez@ub.edu",
"nombre" : "Vanesa",
"movilPersonal" : "934037680",
"apellidos" : "Gonzalez Jimenez."
"direccionTrabajoDTO" : {
  "direccion" : "Feixa Llarga, S\/N 08970 Hospitalet De Llobregat (Barcelona), España"
},
},
```

It's having sub dictioanry.

Then make standard dictionary(final) and set three objects : `plantilla, tempDic and temp array`

So, your object is ready to send.

**Now, don't convert it in json. Convert it in NSdata like below**

If your final dictionary's name is `finalDic` then,

```
   NSData *data = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:finalDic options:0 error:nil];
```

And send that data to server.

If you are using `AFNetworking` then you not need to convert `finalDic` to `data`. `Afnetworking` manage automatically, just pass that `finalDict` as parameter of webservice call by `AFNetworking`.

Hope this will help :)

Answer (score 0):

Please check your json data wrong below url:

http://jsoneditoronline.org/

```
{
"plantilla" : "IL3\/il3_prof",

"contacto" : {
"email" : "vgonzalez@ub.edu",
"nombre" : "Vanesa",
"movilPersonal" : "934037680",
"apellidos" : "Gonzalez Jimenez.",  //Please separate ','
"direccionTrabajoDTO" : {
  "direccion" : "Feixa Llarga, S\/N 08970 Hospitalet De Llobregat (Barcelona), España"
}    // Please remove separete
 },

"valoresPlantilla" : [
{
  "key" : "nombre",
  "value" : "Vanesa Gonzalez Jimenez."
},
{
  "key" : "curso",
  "value" : "Curs de test per Tecnologia"
},
{
  "key" : "linked",
  "value" : "es.linkedin.com\/in\/"
},
{
  "key" : "direccion",
  "value" : "Feixa Llarga, S\/N 08970 Hospitalet De Llobregat (Barcelona), España"
},
{
  "key" : "email",
  "value" : "vgonzalez@ub.edu"
},
{
  "key" : "telefono",
  "value" : "934037680"
 }
]
}
```